# Java spring Boot App not deploying properly from Github using pipeline after adding Procfile in heroku

Tags: github, heroku

I have created an app in heroku and tried adding it for pipeline deployment , But when I integrate the app with github with steps provided in the heroku documentation doesnt help. Looks like target repository is not getting added to the app , or it is not building the app properly after fetching the repo from Github.

I tried manual deployment using heroku Maven plugin and it works fine

Comment: Please give a [mcve], we can't guess what the problem is.